# how to use color-thief in a vuejs context

Tags: vue.js, npm, configuration, vuejs2, package

I'm trying to import `color-thief` from NPM (https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) like this:

```
import ColorThief from 'colorthief'
```

But when I call `new ColorThief()`, it returns something that it is not a constructor. `console.log(ColorThief)` just shows a `_proto_` that I don't understand.

How can use the `color-thief` package properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to install [`null2/color-thief`](https://github.com/null2/color-thief), which is a fork of the original project you linked that allows importing the package.

For example, you could use it in `App.vue` as follows:

1. Install `color-thief` with:

```
npm install -S color-thief
```

2. In `App.vue`'s template, create an `<img>` tag that loads an image you want to analyze. Add a [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to the `<img>` so we could reference it in the next step.

```html
<img ref="myImg" src="...">
```

3. Import `color-thief` in your script, create an instance of `ColorThief`, and then use it to  [`getPalette()`](https://github.com/null2/color-thief#build-a-color-palette-from-an-image) on the `<img>`:

```html
// App.vue
<script>
import ColorThief from 'color-thief'

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const colorThief = new ColorThief()
      const palette = colorThief.getPalette(this.$refs.myImg)
      /* do something with `palette` RGB array */
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/w0x085q337?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)

Comment: @prius I recommend posting two separate questions for your issues so that someone familiar with the topic can answer. You should provide a link to a reproduction of the problem. I'll chime in if I can.